# take value and assign, multiple times with same DIV?

Tags: jquery

I have a template creating the same DIV multiple times.

Inside the DIV there is a name:

```
<div class="left-lg">
    <div class="left-lg-container">
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <img class="img-lg" src=/img/img.jpg alt="" />
    <div class="content">
        <div class="name">Name </div>
        <div class="mentions-hr">1</div>
        <div class="mentions-total">
            <p class="mention-label">Mentions / Hr</p>
            <div class="total-mentions">
                <p class="total-mentions-num left">1</p>
                <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
                <p class="left">Total Mentions</p>
            </div>
            <!-- total-mentions -->
            <div class="share"></div>
            <!-- share -->
        </div>
        <!-- mentions-total -->
    </div>
    <!-- end content -->
    <a href="http://www.link.html"><span></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

for each DIV i'd like to grab that name and assign it to a twitter post:

```
html = '<div class="follow"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="I Like"' + Name + '" data-count="none">Tweet</a></div>';
```

Where is says 'Name'

There can be hundreds of this div on a page and need the specific name in each individual div to be place in the twitter code.

I think its something like this:

```
var Name = $(this).div.name;
```

Comment: No, it's definitely not `$(this).div.name`. I would advise taking the time to actually read the jQuery API docs: http://api.jquery.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var names = [];
$('.left-lg').each(function(){
    names.push($(this).find('.name').text());
});
```

`names` array will contain the names from each of those divs on the page. You can use this array while building the markup for twitter post.

Answer (score 0):

```
html = '';
$('div.name').each(function() {
    var Name = $(this).html();
    html += '<div class="follow"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="I Like"' + Name + '" data-count="none">Tweet</a></div>';
});
```